# Unable to run a python flink application on cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run a **Python Flink Application** on the standalone **Flink** cluster. The application works fine on a single node cluster but it throws the following error on a multi-node cluster. `java.lang.Exception: The user defined 'open()' method caused an exception: An error occurred while copying the file`. Please help me resolve this problem. Thank you

The application I am trying to execute has the following code.

```
from flink.plan.Environment import get_environment
from flink.plan.Constants import INT, STRING, WriteMode

env = get_environment()

data = env.from_elements("Hello")

data.map(lambda x: list(x)).output()
env.execute()
```

Comment: Please provide code for your `open()` method and the full stacktrace. With information you provided so far it is not possible to help you.

Comment: The open() function is actually not user defined but I don't seem to find a solution for this problem. This problem persists only when executed in a multi-node cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure "python.dc.tmp.dir" in "flink-conf.yaml" to point to a distributed filesystem (like HDFS). This directory is used to distributed the python scripts.

Comment: Hi Chesnay, thanks for the reply. Is there way I can set it up without a HDFS system?

Comment: at the moment you unfortunately require some kind of distributed filesystem.

Comment: I have a NFS file system and the error still persists even after configuring "python.dc.tmp.dir"  in the flink-conf.yaml to the shared folder. Please help. Thank you