# Unable to communicate between master node and the worker node in flink application

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to run a flink application on a multi node cluster. I find that the slave node cannot find the  */root/miniconda2/bin/python2.7: can't open file '/root/ranjan/logs/flink-dist-cache-3fc26a73-882a-43eb-bbe9-5984fa0da7ef/d77a4641591fb1d3243e438cde97e746/logs/plan.py*. How to setup a shared NFS system to access the files from the master node in the slave node? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring flink requires only to set "python.dc.tmp.dir" in "flink-conf.yaml" to point to a distributed file system as per [Unable to run a python flink application on cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005505/unable-to-run-a-python-flink-application-on-cluster)

Please consider your Linux distribution's manual on how to set up NFS. Arch Linux' documentation is usually quite good for internals and doing it the manual way: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS

Comment: I have setup a NFS file system, but the error still persists. Is it mandatory to have a hdfs file system?

Comment: The directory specified in "python.dc.tmp.dir" in "flink-conf.yaml" automatically gets deleted from the shared directory. Please help me out.